# Put a Session variable into a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Session variable

```
Session["customerID"]
```

I want to place this inside a textbox. How would I do this?

I have tried

```
TextBox1.Text = Session ["customerID"]
```

Comment: And how did you set up the variable value? "Place inside a textbox" sounds weird...what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want the value of the Session to be in a textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(Session["customerID"] != null)
{
  TextBox1.Text = Session["customerID"].ToString();
}
```

I would add a null check to ensure that your code doesn't fail if the session variable is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You can simply reference it just as you would to store a value into it.

It is important to always check that a particular Key actually exists within the Session as well :

```
if(Session["customerID"] != null) 
{
      TextBox1.Text = Session["customerID"];
}
```

This can also be done as a simple one liner using the ternary (?) operator :

```
TextBox1.Text = Session["customerID"] ?? "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox1.Text = Session ["customerID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

cast the Session object to String and assign it to TextBox:

```
TextBox1.Text = Session ["customerID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this 
 document.getElementById("<%= txtName2.ClientID %>").value = '<%= Session["DmName"].ToString() %>';