# Save a Session to a Label then save back to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to add the Session to a label in my website then save the number saved in the label back to the database. The Session is called `customerID`.

I have been trying to call the Session by doing

```
int vv = (int)Session["customerID"]
Label7.Text = vv; 
//I know this doesn't work but can't work out what I need to make the label display the variable.
```

I then am trying to save it back to the database like so

```
newCarsRow.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(Label7.Text.Trim());
```

My question is how do I get the label to display the int saved in `customerID`

Comment: Why are you setting a session variable value to a label (which is used for display, not maintaining data between postbacks) and then using the label value for your update, instead of just using the Session variable itself? Also, is the customerID for the currently logged in user?

Comment: Yes this is for the logged in user.

Comment: This looks remarkably similar [to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529064/put-a-session-variable-into-a-textbox), which showed how to set a session value to a label...

Comment: WHO is encouraging this type of questions? Whoever you are, do you care to elaborate why do you think this is a good question? This is a question answered NUMEROUS times and can be easily found in 5minutes on Google.

Answer (score 2):

```
string vv = Session["customerID"].ToString();
Label7.Text = vv;
```

You can't make an int equivalent to the Text property of a Label.